# How do I specify default output channel on routeToRecipients using Spring Integration Java DSL 1.0.0.M3

Tags: spring-integration

Since upgrading to M3 of spring-integration java dsl I'm seeing the following error on any flow using a recipient list router:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: no channel resolved by router and no default output channel defined
```

It's not clear how to actually specify this in M3. There is no output channel option on the endpoint configurer and nothing on the RecipientListRouterSpec. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTEXT-113 there is no more reason to specify `.defaultOutputChannel()`, because the next `.channel()` (or implicit) is used for that purpose. That's because that `defaultOutputChannel` exactly plays the role of standard `outputChannel`. Therefore you have now more formal integration flow:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow recipientListFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("recipientListInput")
            .<String, String>transform(p -> p.replaceFirst("Payload", ""))
            .routeToRecipients(r -> r.recipient("foo-channel", "'foo' == payload")
                    .recipient("bar-channel", m ->
                            m.getHeaders().containsKey("recipient")
                                && (boolean) m.getHeaders().get("recipient")))
            .channel("defaultOutputChannel")
            .handle(m -> ...)
            .get();
        }
```

Where `.channel("defaultOutputChannel")` can be omitted.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that makes sense. But what about the case where the router is my last step in the flow and there is no implicit output channel? That is my case now. A gateway is publishing to this flow which routes, it is awaiting a reply from one of the recipients, and the router itself is failing with the error above.

I can always add .channel("nullChannel") but it seemed a bit clunky.

Comment: Well. Let's convert your case to the XML flow definition! And you'll really end up with `default-output-channel="nullChannel"` :-).

Comment: I think the java dsl reference needs to be updated to remove the "defaultOutputChannel"

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. According to the https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues/77 and its PR we definitely will improve it somehow.